# How can I change gridview cells forecolor by column name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview like this:

[image]

I need to check last column date, if older than today, change forecolor.

I tried like this:

```
DateTime dt;
string today = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
int lastcol = e.Row.Cells.Count - 1;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(e.Row.Cells[lastcol].Text, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    string dtstr = dt.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
    if (dtstr != today)
    {
         e.Row.Cells[lastcol].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

It's working for just column name like this(I know because of DateTime Tryparse...):

[image]

I need to change forecolor of every cells of last column like this(If older than today):

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Did this not work for you?

```
DateTime dt;
GridView myGrid = new GridView();
GridViewRow e = myGrid.SelectRow(0);
int lastcol = e.Row.Cells.Count - 1;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(e.Row.Cells[lastcol].Text, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    if (dt > DateTime.Now)
    {
         for each(GridViewRow current in myGrid.Rows)
         {                 
             current.Cells[lastcol].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not work. I want to change ForeColor if column date(name) older than today. I think Foreach does not work because it is in `if (dtstr != today)`.

Comment: Yes did'nt see that error in your code too. Fixed it. use (dstr > today), and you should use datetime not string to compare

Comment: dtstr and today are string, can't use `>`. I think don't need to use it because just check string value. Not old or new.

Comment: As you want, but i truly think that when you want to compare dates, you compare dates.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you make a foreach that will do the thing :

```
Well if you make a foreach that will do the thing :

DateTime dt;
string today = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
int lastcol = e.Row.Cells.Count - 1;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(e.Row.Cells[lastcol].Text, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    string dtstr = dt.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
    if (dtstr != today)
    {
         foreach (Gridview a in idGridView.Rows)
    {
     a.Cells[7].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
    }   
 }
}
```

Comment: foreach (GridViewRow a in yourGridView.Rows)*

Answer (score 0):

try to make it inside RowDataBound event

```
   protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[GetColumnIndexByName(e.Row, "yourDate")].ForeColor  = System.Drawing.Color.Red ;
    }
}
```

with this halper method

```
int GetColumnIndexByName(GridViewRow row, string SearchColumnName)
        {
            int columnIndex = 0;
            foreach (DataControlFieldCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (cell.ContainingField is BoundField)
                {
                    if (((BoundField)cell.ContainingField).DataField.Equals(SearchColumnName))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                columnIndex++;
            }
            return columnIndex;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do.

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(e.Row.Cells[lastcol].Text, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    string dtstr = dt.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
    if (dtstr != today)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[lastcol].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells[lastcol].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its working for just column name(date) too. Foreach does not working for every rows.